# How to automatically close batch program, but keep java program running?

Tags: windows-7, batch, java, automation

I want to run the command "java -jar mc.jar", then automatically close the batch windows. Is there a way I can do this without closing the java program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using the command [`start`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html).

Start launches a program and then immediately continues executing the script, unless the /wait parameter is given too.

Your batch file would look like this:

```
start "" "java -jar mc.jar"
```

If it's just one command, consider using a shortcut instead of a batch file.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this before, and now I realize that I just had to use `javaw.exe` instead of `java.exe`, since the latter would just open a new batch window in the background.